# Как правильно работает Thread.Sleep(0)?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

```
public void StartWork(Thread ThreadCopy)
    {
        while (ThreadCopy.IsAlive)
            Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, только когда в while придет false, тогда закончится метод StartWork?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Для этого существует метод `Thread.Join()`. Такие циклы только загружают процессор, в то время как метод `Join` имеет нулевую нагрузку.

А по вопросу, да, ваш метод ждет, пока поток завершится.